# Regular expression for accept only 1 occurrence of "space" and "single quote" character among letters

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to validate a String in java to meet below requirement,

1. The letters a to z (upper and lowercase) (zero or many times) - `[a-zA-Z]`
2. The single quote character (zero or one time) - `??`
3. The space character (zero or one time) - `??`
4. Any other character should not be accepted

I tried with many expressions but couldn't get to work with the number of occurrences (2nd and 3rd point)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please share the best try to see where it went wrong. Note `[a-aA-Z]` does not match `b` and other lowercase letters other than `a`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry it was a typo. Edited to `[a-zA-Z]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 quote | space ||
-------+-------++-----
   0   |   0   || ^[a-z]*$
   0   |   1   || ^[a-z]* [a-z]*$
   1   |   0   || ^[a-z]*'[a-z]*$
   1   |   1   || ^[a-z]* [a-z]*'[a-z]*$ or ^[a-z]*'[a-z]* [a-z]*$
```

Eg.

```
final Pattern regex = Pattern
        .compile("^([a-z]*|[a-z]* [a-z]*|[a-z]*'[a-z]*|[a-z]* [a-z]*'[a-z]*|[a-z]*'[a-z]* [a-z]*)$",
                CASE_INSENSITIVE);

for(String x: asList("", "'", " ", "' '", " a ", "p%q", "aB cd'Ef", "'dF gh"))
    System.out.printf("%s <= \"%s\"%n", regex.matcher(x).matches(), x);
```

With output:

```
true <= ""
true <= "'"
true <= " "
false <= "' '"
false <= " a "
false <= "p%q"
true <= "aB cd'Ef"
true <= "'dF gh"
```

Comment: better use `matches()` instead of  `find()` and `"^...$"` (*want* to match, not find some text)

Answer (score -1):

To mention, another idea can be to use a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
^(?!.*?([ ']).*\1)[a-zA-Z ']+$
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FKuF2l/4)

Inside the lookahead `([ '])` [captures](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) any of [the characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), that are allowed only once. `\1` checks for re-occurrence by [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to what was captured in **group 1** with `.*` [anything](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) in between.

This pattern allows to easily add more characters that must not occure more than once.

Comment: How can I modify this to accept `numbers 0 to 9 (between zero and three times)` ?

Comment: @ChamithraThenuwara You could add digits to the character class and add another negative lookahead at start to disallow 4 or more digits: [`^(?!(?:\D*\d){4})(?!.*([ ']).*\1)[a-zA-Z\d ']+$`](https://regex101.com/r/FKuF2l/2)

Comment: You're welcome! Those lookhead things are advanced stuff but once understood it's easy and useful :) BTW you can also pipe both negative conditions into one negative lookahead: [`^(?!(?:\D*\d){4}|.*([ ']).*\1)[a-zA-Z\d ']+$`](https://regex101.com/r/FKuF2l/3)